# Unwrapping Matrix on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to construct a `C` matrix from a `B` matrix by following these instructions : If I have a matrix `B = B0 + B1 + ... + Bs = [B0 ; B1 ;...; Bs]` where  `s` is a natural number and `B` is of dimension  `n1 * n2`.

Then the matrix  `C` is obtained by :

[image]

The dimension of B is : `n1 * n2`

The dimension of C is : `(L+s) * n1 * Ln2`

Example : `B = [3 3] = B0 + B1 + B2 = [1 1] + [1 1] + [1 1] = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]` with `s = 2` and `L = 4`

The matrix `C` is is obtained by:

[image]

With dimension : `B = 1 * 2` and `C = (4+2)*1*4*2 = 6 * 8`

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix notation does not make a lot of sense, specially in MATLAB, as you write:

```
[1 1] + [1 1] + [1 1] = [1 1 ; 1 1 ; 1 1]
```

This equality is not true, as the LHS has size `[1 2]`, while the RHS has dimension `[3 2]`. If you could explain better this, then we can try a more general code.

---

To solve the example you provided:

```
B = [1 1
    1 1
    1 1];
s = 2;
L = 4;

c = [B ; zeros(size(B))];
C = zeros(L+s,L*s);
for ii=1:L
    C(:,2*ii-1:2*ii) = circshift(c,ii-1,1);
end
```

> ```
> C =
>
>      1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
>      1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
>      1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
>      0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
>      0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
>      0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
> ```

There is probably a better, one-line solution avoiding the for-loop, however.

Comment: You're right there's a mistake, it normally : `B = [3 3] = [1,1] + [1,1] + [1,1]`

Comment: You should initialize `C` to the right size, rather than concatenating inside the loop. Concatenation is very slow.

Comment: That is true. I changed that.

Comment: Thanks @ Thales.